# Width and height of UICollectionViewCell 's subviews is zero

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I had been stuck at this issue where I wanted to set frame, corner radius and other manipulations on the `CALayer` present in the `UICollectionViewCell` after the autolayout is complete. But to my surprise the subviews of the cell and it contentView were appearing a `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` everytime `layoutSubviews()` was called in the cell's subclass. I have finally found solution to this issue and am posting it so everyone can have a look at this if you are facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had been banging my head for over a week now, but finally! This is what worked perfectly for me:

Implement `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)` function of the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and trigger a new layout cycle for the `contentView` of the cell the `collectionView` is about to display.

**Swift:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     cell.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
     cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     [cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
     [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

This might appear to be very cumbersome operation but every time the collection view inserts a new cell and enforces autolayout, the `frame`s of the cells are usually `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` after the initial layout cycle (as observed in `layoutSubviews()`) but if layout is triggered manually just before the cell is about the appear on screen, the `frame`s of subviews observed in `layoutSubviews()` are what you hope to expect after autolayout cycle completion.

Make sure you trigger autolayout in the `contentView` and not just the cell itself This manual trigger might appear cumbersome, but that the best I got.